Can't find IncludePath to SDL2/SDL.h
I'm setting up SDL in VSCode by this website https://dev.to/giovannicodes/setup-sdl2-with-visual-studio-code-and-mingw64-on-windows-14c5
and I'm stuck on including the path in C/C++ Configurations
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argv, char** args)
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);

    SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow("Hello SDL", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 800, 600, 0);
    SDL_Renderer *renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);

    bool isRunning = true;
    SDL_Event event;

    while (isRunning)
    {
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
        {
            switch (event.type)
            {
            case SDL_QUIT:
                isRunning = false;
                break;

            case SDL_KEYDOWN:
                if (event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_ESCAPE)
                {
                    isRunning = false;
                }
            }
        }

        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 0, 0, 255);

        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    }

    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}

It says that I should update my includePath but I don't know where it is.
I have searched it on the internet but I've not found anything.
I have tried the path:
${workspaceFolder}/**
...Visual Studio Code\MinGW\ucrt64\include
and I think it's wrong but where is it then?

I would argue that the tutorial gives you bad advice from the start. You should not download sdl at all. Instead you should install sdl using pacman just like you installed MinGW like the official VSCode MinGW instructions told you to do: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw

Let's see tasks.json. The compiler invocation is probably missing a -I<path to SDL include folder>

It says that I should update my includePath but I don't know where it is. Please read and understand the official VSCode MinGW instructions I gave you in the first link. It will explain the 3 json import files and how to install MinGW and show you how to use pacman.

The tutorial is telling you to add the mingw/x86_64/include folder in your SDL installation. I can't tell you where that is because I don't know where you installed SDL, but you should be able to figure it out.

Forget about JSON files and use a proper build system. VSCode is terrible at this.

I do agree that using CMake would be much better but at the same time then you need to learn some CMake in addition.
